# SpriteKit - multiple contact bit masks for one object

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

How can I define several types of objects a certain object can contact to in SpriteKit? For example: I want to be notified with a SKPhysicsContact if either my hero contacts with an enemy, or with an enemyBullet.

I found `ball.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = BodyType.gap.rawValue | BodyType.wall.rawValue` in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29311429/multiple-contacts-issue-in-spritekit-game) Stackoverflow post. However, if i try so, Compiler tells me: `Consecutive Statements on a line must be separated by ";".`

I tried: `player.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.enemy | PhysicsCategory.enemyBullet`

Thanks! I am using Swift 2.1 on iOS 9.2

Comment: that is the correct way to do it, so you need to post more code,  particularly whatever BodyType and PhysicsCategory is

Comment: @Knight0fDragon: Now thats funny: I restarted my XCode. After that it still showed me a bug, telling me that on my "player.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.enemy | PhysicsCategory.enemyBullet" line i need to replace " " with " ". After that it worked... XCode is weird!